# Any arbitrary closed smooth curve bounds a orientable surface?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I've got a question that, given an arbitrary closed smooth curve $C:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, can you always find a orientable surface $\Omega$ which satisfy $\partial\Omega=C[0,1]$ ?

I have no idea on this question, and I suppose that the surface $\Omega$ has no restriction such as “smooth”. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen There are some concepts I cannot hold. Is a closed smooth curve always able to be classified as knot, unknot or links? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do we know that $C$ does not intersect itself, i.e. that $C$ restricted to the half-open interval $\left[ 0 , 1 \right[$ is injective?

Then the orientable surface exists, can be taken to be compact and connected, and is then called a [Seifert surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface) of the knot.

Comment: Yes, C is not self-intersection. However is there any counter-example when C is self-intersection?

Comment: @WildChan Not sure. I think the surface may need to have more than one connected component, then? I don't know, but I'm thinking of a figure-eight curve?

Comment: Maybe I am not very careful in distinguishing a Seifert surface of _some_ curve which is topologically the same knot as $C$, and then a surface which really has your exact $C$ image as its boundary. If something is missing here, please comment.